# Connect Intelligent Power Manager with EATON EDX2000H and WebPower SNMP Card II

Tags: vmware-esxi, snmp, ups

We have an EATON EDX2000H, a WebPower SNMP Card II and I have just installed Intelligent Power Manager.

I cannot make IPM to see the UPS as power source. It is greyed out (img 1).

IPM sees the UPS and its state though. The node driver is automatically selected as "UPS RFC1628 / SNMP"

Has anyone encountered this before? Is it a compatibility issue?

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/occvq.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look, your DX UPS is not compatible with basic IPM, mind you, there are incompatibilities in the design:
1- DX UPS is not compatible with basic IPM, DX is a third-party device for IPM, so you need IPM Silver or Gold to implement shutdown.

2- Every virtualization system to be shutdown via the IPM from third-party UPS need SILVER or GOLD IPM license.

Courtesy of Support Eaton Brazil.